# The 'include' of 'spl_autoload_register' can't find the path

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I can use a class with *include* and *use* but I failed with spl_autoload_register.

I tried different methods without success.

What's work fine:

```
include "MesProduits/Produit.php";
use MesProduits\Produit;
```

or

```
function monAutoLoad() {
    include "MesProduits/Produit.php";
} 
spl_autoload_register('monAutoload'); 
use MesProduits\Produit;
```

But the code below failed:

```
function monAutoLoad($class) { 
    include  "MesProduits/" . $class . ".php"; 
} 
spl_autoload_register('monAutoload');
use MesProduits\Produit;
```

or

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'MesProduits/' . $class . '.php';
});
use MesProduits\Produit;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$class` be `MesProduits\Produit` in `monAutoLoad()` and thus end up trying to include `"MesProduits/" . 'MesProduits\Produit' . ".php"`?

Comment: I don't think so because in the book I read, the author explain that the goal is to avoid many 'include' and only write 'use...' when I need a class.

Comment: The string that is passed to the callback for `spl_autoload_register` is the fully qualified class name. If you have `use X\Y\Z; new Z();` and `new \X\Y\Z();`, they will both pass `X\Y\Z` as the class name. Similarly, if you have `namespace X\Y; new Z();`. I would recommend running `var_dump($class)` inside the callback to see what is being passed.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I move the Produit.php file at the same level than index.php but that didn't fix anything. The problem was in the include's path. spl_autoload_register receive a variable with a backslash but the include inside the function was waiting a path with a slash. I think it's a common problem with MacOS and Unix system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that **use** needs backslash for the **spacename** and **include** needs slash for the path of the file.php where I have the classes.
I'm on MacOS X and I read using a Mac generates this kind of problem.

The solution was using a **str_replace** to convert **\** in **/**.

```
function monAutoLoad($class) {
    include(str_replace("\\", "/", $class). ".php");
}

spl_autoload_register('monAutoLoad');

use MesProduits\Produit;
```